# curl request does not returns data when call through localhost

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am calling an API from a remote server using php curl POST request.

The problem is that when I send the request using localhost it does not return any data. But when I upload it to my server and then send the request. It works perfectly well. Do you have any idea why it might be happening, I am running wamp on local machine and LAMP on web server

Answer (score 1):

I think you should print phpinfo() and to check do you really have curl on your LAMP